# find() for multiple results

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm using find as that in order to select inner

```
$(".pauseAnomaly[data-id=78]").parent().parent().prev().find(".pauseaction").each(function (i) {
                                pauseActionUI($(this).data("id"));
                            });
```

I want to launch `.pauseAction` on each `.pauseAction` found in `$(".pauseAnomaly[data-id=78]").parent().parent().prev().`

Here, it works perfect when there is single `.pauseaction` but nothing when there is multiple `.pauseaction`, why? and how resolve this?

In other words

When I do

```
$(".pauseAnomaly[data-id=35]").parent().parent().prev().find(".pauseaction").each(function (i) {
                                alert($(this).data("id"));
                            });
```

where there is one `.pauseaction`, it returns one id, but when there is multiple `.pauseaction`, it returns me `[]`, but I wound like to see all id's and apply funcito to all of them, why and how?

I think `find()` only returns one element, so if it's true, how can I make change in order to have all elemetns?

Here is the code when I `$(".pauseAnomaly[data-id=14]").parent().parent().prev()`

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-top-width:0;padding-top:0;padding-left:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;">
                <table class="table table-striped" style="margin-bottom:0;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="actionRow actionRow" data-id="9">
                            <td><span class="glyphicon spaceAfterIcon vorx late glyphicon-remove red" data-id="9"></span></td>
                            <td>TEXT</td>
                            <td>TEXT</td>
                            <td class="date" data-id="9">03/04/2015</td>
                            <td>SELECT</td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment commentAction red" data-actiondescr="Reparer le chauffage (date de fin plann. depassée)" data-actionid="9" data-id="9"></span> | <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause red pauseAction" data-id="9"></span> <span class="closeActionButtons" data-id="9">| <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle red closeOKAction" data-id="9"></span>/ <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle red closeNOKAction" data-id="9"></span></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="actionRow desactivatedColor actionRow" data-id="10">
                            <td><span class="glyphicon spaceAfterIcon vorx late" data-id="10"></span></td>
                            <td>TEXT</td>
                            <td>TEXT</td>
                            <td class="date" data-id="10">03/04/2015</td>
                            <td>SELECT</td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment commentAction red" data-actiondescr="Installer un thermostat pour réguler le chauffage" data-actionid="10" data-id="10"></span> | <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-play red playAction" data-id="10"></span> <span class="closeActionButtons" data-id="10" style="display:none;">| <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle red closeOKAction" data-id="10"></span>/<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle red closeNOKAction" data-id="10"></span></span></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="actionRow actionRow" data-id="13">
                            <td><span class="glyphicon spaceAfterIcon vorx late glyphicon-remove red" data-id="13"></span></td>
                            <td>TEXT</td>
                            <td>TEXT</td>
                            <td class="date" data-id="13">27/03/2012</td>
                            <td>SELECT</td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment commentAction red" data-actiondescr="Action closed" data-actionid="13" data-id="13"></span> | <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-pause red pauseAction" data-id="13"></span> <span class="closeActionButtons" data-id="13">| <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle red closeOKAction" data-id="13"></span>/ <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle red closeNOKAction" data-id="13"></span></span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Provide all relevant code in question (`pauseActionUI()`, HTML markup???) because as i see it, it should work. FYI, you have better to use `parents('selector')` or `closest('selector')` method instead of `parent().parent()`

Comment: Please provide the involved html as well.

Comment: @A.Wolff : thanks for your attention. pauseActionUI just make some changes on the element, For the issue, we can consider to replace ActionUI by a alert(""). i've added HTML

Comment: I don't see any element matching `".pauseAnomaly[data-id=35]"` selector?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the case of the selector as it needs to be `pauseAction` as opposed to `pauseaction`. Below is a demo that clarifies it.

```
$("table").find(".pauseAction").each(function (i) {
    alert($(this).data("id"));
});
```

So, your code would become (provided `.pauseAnomaly[data-id=14]` selector exists!):

```
$(".pauseAnomaly[data-id=14]").parent().parent().prev().find(".pauseAction").each(function (i) {
    alert($(this).data("id"));
});
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezvh7sqe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try in your each function:

```
$(this)[i].data('id')
```

If that doesnt work try:

```
$($(this)[i]).data('id')
```

What I've done is select the element that you found and as it is an array you are selecting the specific index in the loop

For example if i = 2 in the loop the selector would look like:

```
$(this)[2].data('id')
```

which would return the 3 element in that array

Comment: `data()` is a jQuery method, `[x]` returns a DOM node. So instead use `.eq(x)`